# Set Apache Server to listen in wi-fi network interface ip address on windows

Tags: apache-http-server

How to setup apache server to listen on a dynamic taken ip address of a wi-fi network adapter on windows 11 ?

The ip is from a only local wi-fi access point that have a dhcp running on it (dd wrt installed).

I tried to configure like this, in httpd.conf file, but not worked: Listen ip.address.of.Wi-Fi:80

Notes:
https://serverfault.com/questions/1135196/set-apache-server-to-listen-in-wi-fi-network-interface-ip-address-on-windows
https://forum.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=334771 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76576284/config-apache-server-to-take-an-ip-from-an-access-point
I asked the question here but it hasn't been approved by the community, so it doesn't appear: https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewforum.php?f=5

Thank's.

Comment: If the datastream is encrypted (https or Outlook), good luck,